# How to use auto-configured beans in (unit) tests while having manually configured beans in main?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm interested in how to wire things differently in the test environment.
I have a special scenario in which I would like to have Oracle AQ queues in *main* and ActiveMQ queues in *test*.

I'm using Spring Boot and I figured out how to get Oracle AQ to work. I'm using Java configuration.

## OracleAQ

In the main config I define the following beans (only the relevant imo):

- JmsListenerContainerFactory (DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory) (needed by JmsListener)
- ConnectionFactory (AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory) (needed by JmsTemplate and ContainerFactory)
- DataSource (OracleDataSource) (needed by ConnectionFactory)

Is use:

```
org.springframework:spring-jms
javax.jms:jms
javax.transaction:jta
com.oracle:aqapi
com.oracle:ojdbc8
org.springframework.data:spring-data-oracle
```

## ActiveMQ

Also, currently in a different project, I have a default ActiveMQ setup.
There I only define one bean (maybe I can even do without it):

- JmsListenerContainerFactory (DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory).

Automatically wired is the:

- ConnectionFactory (ActiveMQConnectionFactory)

  - and this connectionfactory has no datasource (activemq on vm memory)

I use:

```
org.springframework:spring-jms
javax.jms:jms
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq
org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker
```

## Oracle AQ and ActiveMQ combined

Now I would like to combine both approaches: having OracleAQ in main and ActiveMQ in test.

- I started with adding the Oracle dependencies. No problem yet.
- Then I define the DataSource (OracleDataSource) bean. No problem yet.
- Then I define the ConnectionFactory (needed for jmstemplate and containerfactory). Problem: the *main* now has the right ConnectionFactory, but the *test* has this ConnectionFactory too. I want to get the ActiveMQConnectionFactory, but get the AQjmsQueueConnectionFactory in *test*. Previously this was automagically auto-configured and wired for me.

So I guess my question is really: How to use auto-configured beans in *test* while *main* has manually configured beans of the same interface?

In this case it is hard (encapsulated code) to reassemble the auto-configured bean by hand in the *test* environment, so I'm thinking in the direction of ignoring *main* beans or so.
Another idea is to create an auto-configure myself.

Any other ideas? tips? examples?

I think it should be fairly easy with the idea of dependency injection, but I'm not sure how.

I also think this case might be very specific to queueing an may be generalised to, for example, *using database type * (postgres for example) in main and H2 in test*.

Thanks

*EDIT*:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html explains how to replace auto-configuration with your own beans. What I need is the other way around.